# Angular 2 change detection not working

Tags: angular

I have been trying to save my products to the cart however it doesn't seem to be rendering.

I have tried these technique to detect changes

```
ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()

NgZone.run(callback) 

ChangeDetectionStrategy
```

```js
export class CartPageComponent implements OnInit{

  cart: any;
  ids: any;

  constructor(private storage: LocalStorageService, private Product: ProductService ){
    this.cart = [];
    this.ids = [];
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    if(!this.storage.get('cart')){
      this.cart = this.storage.get('cart');
      return;
    }
    this.cart = JSON.parse(this.storage.get('cart'));
    this.ids = this.cart.map(function(item){
      return item.id;
    });
    
    // make http request and response will get back the data from the observable
    this.Product.getCartProducts(this.ids, function(response){
        this.cart = response.data;
    }.bind(this));

  }
}
```

If anyone has any clue to update cart after the component has loaded and the HTTP request is still running that would be a great start.

Comment: Are you using the angular `http` service? If not, do it, it returns an Observable which can be later bound to your template via RxJs and the `async` pipe. (Why people still using callbacks with Angular and XHR requests :( ? [and if you need, it's typescript use arrow functions, and not `bind(this)`) OT: please don't write your class members with uppercase, it's quite confusing `private Product: ProductService` => `private productService: ProductService` || `private product: ProductService`

Comment: Give more code , your service code too